# Swapped sparge by mash water quantities

Tags: all-grain, sparge, mashing, small-batch

When it was (potentially) too late I've noticed that I've used the 4L of water for mashing that I should've used for sparging - which was instead 3L. Could this be a problem? The end amount is the same. I've also noticed that the mashing temperature was very stable (probably due to higher water volume).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.5 gallon batch?

You should fine. The higher grain to water ratio may result in a slightly high pH but you should still be well in the range for enzymes to do their work.

Comment: Yes, 4L batch - not much space in the house :-). Just checked, and the airlock seems to be bubbling.

Comment: Just to add some more info. The beer turned out slightly better than the first batch actually :-)